# Issue rotating UIImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios6

I'm developing an iOS 6 app for iPad. I've developed some code which rotates a `UIImage`. It works great with square images, but when the images aren't square they get cropped, so you only see a part of the image (a square).

My code:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size);

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextTranslateCTM( context, 0.5f * image.size.width, 0.5f * image.size.height ) ;
CGContextRotateCTM( context, -1.5707963267949) ;

[image drawInRect:(CGRect){ { -imatgetemporal.size.width * 0.5f, -image.size.height * 0.5f }, image.size }];

UIImage *imageCopy = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
```

I think the problem is in the 0.5f, but I don't know how to solve it. 
What can I do?

Comment: The issue may well be in the 0.5. It is certainly related to the size and position of your rect. Naturally when a rect is rotated by other angles than multipliers of 90 degrees then the resulting bounding box, the enclosing rectangle, is larger than the original. Its top left corner moves as well. You may try drawAtPoint instead. So you do not need to calculate the exact frame of the bounding box around the rotated rectangle. But you will still need to consider the move of the top left point within the coordinate system.

Comment: So how could I do that?

Comment: I mean the code. [image drawAtPoint....

Comment: [image drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0,0)]; Assuming the top left edge is (0,0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your graphics context big enough for the rotated image.  You're using image.size, but should be using a the rotated size as the argument to UIGraphicsBeginImageContext.  Additionally, your argument to drawInRect is incorrect.  You need to offset the (rotated) origin x, which determines the y origin of the final image, in the following way:  "Up" by half the original height (which puts the final image entirely off the top of the drawing context) then "down" by the full original width, which is the final image height.

```
const CGSize imageSize = image.size;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(imageSize.height, imageSize.width));

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.5f * imageSize.width, 0.5f * imageSize.height ) ;
CGContextRotateCTM(context, -1.5707963267949) ;
[image drawInRect:(CGRect){ { imageSize.height * 0.5 - imageSize.width, -imageSize.width * 0.5f }, imageSize }];

UIImage *imageCopy = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
```

Comment: I doesn't work... Now I can only see a vertical part of the image, like a 1/8 of the total length.

Comment: @MartiSerraVivancos Sorry, I wrote hastily last night.  I've edited my answer and the positing code.  I've tested the new version on a few different image sizes and I'm fairly confident that it will work for you.